# Comparing Scala and Java Double.NaN

Tags: java, scala, nan

Why does this comparison evaluate to `true`?

```
scala> Double.NaN equals java.lang.Double.NaN
res5: Boolean = true
```

But this one evaluates to `false`?

```
scala> Double.NaN == java.lang.Double.NaN
res6: Boolean = false
```

aside: [this](https://twitter.com/propensive/status/456377217467961344) interesting Twitter thread prompted me to ask this question

Comment: Their value is equal, but their instance isn't.

Comment: @Obicere, could you expand on your answer and explain which one of those operators is doing the reference comparison and which one is doing the value comparison?

Comment: Some discussion about this on the scala-language alias: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-language/LJGpb1wDjI4/HgE8jcGbL0YJ

Comment: Hey @AmigoNico. Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your detailed answer

Comment: No problem, Kevin -- glad it helped!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not about Scala's NaN vs. Java's -- there is only one NaN:

```
scala> val a = Double.NaN
a: Double = NaN

scala> val b = java.lang.Double.NaN
b: Double = NaN
```

Nor is it about there being two objects with the same value.  It's about [the definition of NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).  Two NaNs are not == because that's the way NaN is defined -- it is *not a number*, but rather a special value that means "undefined."  If you have two of those, how would you know whether they are equal?  For example:

```
scala> val x = 0.0 / 0.0
x: Double = NaN

scala> val y = Math.sqrt(-1)
y: Double = NaN

scala> x == y
res9: Boolean = false
```

Fortunately they are not ==; they are not numbers whose values you can compare.

As for `x.equals(y)`, well, why would you do that in Scala?  But given that you did, you are running into the bit of Java weirdness that I.K. pointed us to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for.  Let's demonstrate it:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    double nan1 = 0.0 / 0.0;        Double box1 = nan1;
    double nan2 = Math.sqrt(-1);    Double box2 = nan2;
    System.out.println( nan1 == nan2 );         // false, as expected
    System.out.println( box1.equals(box2) );    // true -- WTF???
  }
}
```

Comment: "As for x.equals(y), well, why would you do that?"  I don't know about Scala, but in Java, if you're comparing the value of two big-D `Double`s, you'd *better* do that!

Comment: @AndrewBissell this may be OT, but reading `two big-D Doubles` just sounded so funny.

Comment: @AndrewBissell Yes, but Scala is not Java; in Scala, `==` does not always mean reference equality, like it does in Java.

Comment: In Scala for reference types (subtypes of `AnyRef`) `==` always compiles to a call to the LHS `equals` method. Reference equality is written `eq`.

Comment: @RandallSchulz That is not strictly true, there is some null handling going on as well. In Scala `null == "not null"` is false, but `null.equals("not null")` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner, could you please provide a link or example? I'm interested to know more.

Comment: @KevinMeredith See 6.3 in http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html. It describes the differing behavior of `==` and `equals` for the `Null` object.

Answer (score 3):

`Double.NaN` is the same as `java.lang.Double.NaN`, as AmigoNice already said. It's a `Double` (or `double` in Java terms). So using `==` on it is the same as `==` in Java and returns `false` for two NaNs, as expected. However, using `equals` forces the compiler to box both sides to `java.lang.Double`, and `Double.equals` is defined to return `true` in this case (which I just learned and which surprised me).

Comment: does it seem wrong that using `equals` on two `NaN`s results in `true`?

Comment: It does to me, since it's a difference from `==` for `double`.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> Double.NaN equals java.lang.Double.NaN
res5: Boolean = true
```

This evaluates to `true` because `Double.NaN` is equivalent to `java.lang.Double.NaN`. Consequently, the `equals` method for `java.lang.Double` is called. According to the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), for two `doubles`, d1 and d2, if d1 and d2 both represent `Double.NaN`, then the `equals` method returns `true`, even though the value should be `false` according to IEEE specification.

```
scala> Double.NaN == java.lang.Double.NaN
res6: Boolean = false
```

This evaluates to `false` because Scala's `==` operator follows the IEEE specification. It does not call down to the Java `==` operator. Also, `NaN` is not a number as mentioned by @AmigoNico. It is a place holder for a large number of "invalid" values. There is no way of knowing whether two NaN's are equal, because they could be represented by two different "invalid" values.